# Async.map in vorpal command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, vorpal.js

I'm creating a command line in node js so I'm using Vorpal to do so but I have a problem when I try to use Async library (Async.map) so the command line never stops.

So here is my code:

First I use Async.applyEachSeries to map every command available like this

```
let commands = [Users];

Async.applyEachSeries(commands, program, (err) => {
  //If no command available enter in interactive mode
});
```

//Users.js

Register the command for managing users

```
module.exports = (program, done) => {

  program
    .command('createUsers <file>', 'Create firebase users')
    .action(internals.createUsers(program));

  done();
};
```

And the internals.createUsers reads the file and calls the firebase API in order to create users like this

```
internals.createUsers = (program) => (args, done) => {
  internals
  .parse(args.file)
  .then(users => {
    async.mapLimit(users, 2, (user, cb) => {

      program.firebaseAdmin.auth()
      .createUser({
        email: user.email,
        emailVerified: true,
        password: user.password,
        displayName: user.name,
        disabled: false
       })
       .then(userRecord => {
         return cb(null,Object.assign(user,{status: 'new'}));
       })
       .catch(err => {
         if (err.code == 'auth/email-already-exists') {
           return cb(null,Object.assign(user,{status: 'email-already-exists'}));
         }
         return cb(err);
       });

    },(err,results) => {

      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      console.log(results);
      done(null,'ok');
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    done(err);
  })
}
```

Works fine (the last console.log(results) prints out correctly) but the program never ends.

I have been testing it part by part and then problem happens when I introduce firebase promise into the mix, perhaps it doesn't works ok with Async...

Comment: is the callback for `.action` required to return anything? because yours doesn't

Comment: the internals.createUsers = (program) => (args, done) => {} returns a function that acts as the callback

Comment: indeed, but is that function ... `(args, done) => {}` meant to return anything?

Comment: According to Vorpal documentation you need to call the callback (done) in my case when the action if finished
  .action(function(args, callback) {
    this.log('bar');
    callback();
  });... and I think I'm calling done after async.mapLimit right?

Comment: ahh, yes, sorry, didn't see the `done`